# Appropriate location for daemons and launch agents

Tags: macos, installation, defaultlocation

We're developing a system that consists of a daemon, a server and a gui launch agent. As each of these components are not launched by the user, I'd rather keep them out of the /Applications folder.

We will **not** be distributing via the App Store.

Apple's documentation for [Daemons and Launch Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-104142-BCICCCFI) states: -

> *The appropriate location for executables that you launch from your job is **/usr/local/libexec.***

I was considering using the location /usr/local/libexec, but it is not present on OS X 10.8, 10.9 and 10.0.

I also considered /Library/Application Support, but the docs clearly state that this location is meant for support files to applications, which an application can still run without their presence.

So, should I be creating /usr/local/libexec and using that location, or is there a better location for these executables to be installed?